# Get object from encrypted bucket using boto2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

Is it possible to get files from encrypted S3 buckets using boto 2?  I am working with a project that uses S3 in several places and has to read/write to an encrypted S3 bucket.  I would like to make as small a change as possible, for the time being, to support encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Encryption actually works at the *object* level, rather than the *bucket*.

There are several ways to use encryption. If it is [Protecting Data Using Server-Side Encryption with Amazon S3-Managed Encryption Keys (SSE-S3)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html), then as long as your app has permission to access the object then it will be automatically decrypted. (The app won't even notice that it was encrypted!)

If it is [Protecting Data Using Server-Side Encryption with AWS KMS–Managed Keys (SSE-KMS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingKMSEncryption.html), the app will also need adequate permissions to use the key in KMS. The object will be automatically decrypted, but it needs permissions to use the key.

If the app is [Protecting Data Using Server-Side Encryption with Customer-Provided Encryption Keys (SSE-C)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html), then the app must provide the encryption key when it tries to access the object.

And finally, if it is [Protecting Data Using Client-Side Encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingClientSideEncryption.html), then the app is totally responsible for encryption/decryption.

It is most likely that your data is using **Server-Side Encryption with Amazon S3-Managed Encryption Keys (SSE-S3)**. If so, then your app doesn't have to do anything — it will all be handled automagically by Amazon S3.